# Redirect from a feed of components to an individual component

Tags: reactjs

**Goal:** I have a feed of different artworks. I want to click on one of the artworks and redirect to a new page with data from the **clicked artwork** only.

Question: How do I ensure that when an individual artwork is clicked that I can redirect to a new page with data from only the clicked artwork and not the entire feed?

Here is the code from my `Feed` component where I query for all of the artwork and render them into the feed:

```js
function Feed() {
  const [artworks, setArtworks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("artworks")
      .where("status", "==", "true")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setArtworks(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
      );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="artwork__feed">
        {artworks.map((artwork) => (
          <FeedCard
            imageUrl={artwork.imageUrl}
            title={artwork.title}
            artist={artwork.artist}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

I then pass the props into my `FeedCard` component like this:

```
function FeedCard({
  imageUrl,
  title,
  artist,
 
}) {

  
  return (
    <div className="feed__card">
        <div className="feed__card__container" onClick={grabArtworkId}>
          <div className="feed__category">
            <img src={imageUrl} className="artwork__image__feed" />
          </div>
          <div className="artwork__info">
            <div className="artwork__title__artist">
              <h1>{title}</h1>
              <p>{artist}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="artwork__bid_button">
              <button>Bid</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, when someone clicks on and individual `FeedCard` component, how can I redirect the user to a new page with data only pulled from that particular card? I was trying link and querying by the `doc.id` but I couldn't get that to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you are rendering your `FeedCard` components you already have access to the whole `artwork` object for an individual artwork correct? Or is there more information that you mean to display on this individual page.

Comment: @CoryHarper Nope, I don't need any more info. I just want to take the data from an individual card and populate it on a new page. Right now, it populates everything I have in my db instead of an individual object

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom).

Your parent component will end up looking something like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Feed />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/artwork">
          <Artwork />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
};
```

Then when someone clicks one of your `FeedCard`s you could use the `history` object to pass along the state to your `Artwork` component.

```js
history.push({
  pathname: '/artwork',
  state: {
    imageUrl,
    title,
    artist,
  }
})
```

Which can be accessed by using the `useHistory` hook.

If you do not wish to use react-router, I suggest that you render either component conditionally in your parent similar to the `Switch` in the react-router code I've supplied.

Comment: Should I include the history.push()... code in the FeedCard component or in the Feed component?

Comment: Wherever you decide you add the `onClick` handler.